# Calculating the Brier score for multinomial models

Tags: r, logistic, multinomial-distribution, accuracy, brier-score

I was wondering whether it is possible to calculate the Brier score for multinomial models in R?

For example:

```
library(nnet)
data(iris)
mlogit <- multinom(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

and given the definition of the Brier score for multinomial model on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score). I do not believe I can compute the Brier score, because I lack the class probabilities of the non-realized classes for each observation right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[doi:10.1002/sim.5321](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.5321) may give you some ideas.  I don't think an overall Brier score for polytomous outcomes has been fully worked out.  But at least you could report $k-1$ Brier scores for predicting the probability of $k-1$ out of the $k$ levels of $Y$.

Comment: Dear Frank; A bit of a long shot I am sure but I wonder if you still have any of these references to hand please, given that citeUlike is no more.

Comment: Fixed above - thanks.

Comment: Great, thank you.